# Não estou conseguindo exibir os dados do array

Tags: javascript, json

quando eu digito o comando console.log(response) ele exibe todas as informações no console do navegador, mas por algum detalhe, não estou conseguindo exibir os dados dentro da minha div que está no trecho do html lá embaixo. Alguém pode me apontar o que estou deixando passar?

```
<script>
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
      }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    myFunction(url);
    function myFunction(response) {
        var arr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
        var i;
        var out = "<div>";

        for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            out += "<a href='#' class='samba-playlist-trigger list-group-item active' data-mediaid=" + arr[i].id + "></a>";
        }
        out += "</div>";
        document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
    }
</script>
```

A parte de exibição na página html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="id01"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Qual a ideia de `myFunction(url);`? e onde estás a instanciar o ajax? Outra coisa, o `JSON.stringify` não faz sentido pois estás a receber uma string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Três coisas que me ocorrem:

- Qual a ideia de `myFunction(url);`? essa linha não faz sentido pois `myFunction` é o que queres usar para processar o resultado do ajax certo?
- falta o código que instancia o ajax
- o `JSON.stringify` não faz sentido pois estás a receber uma string.

Sugestão:

```js
function chamarAjax(url, callback) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', url, true);

  request.onload = function() {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
      callback(request.responseText);
    } else {
      console.log('Houve um erro!');
    }
  };

  request.onerror = function() {
    console.log('Houve um erro!');
  };

  request.send();
}

function myFunction(response) {
  var arr = JSON.parse(response);
  var ancoras = arr.map(function(obj) {
    return "<a href='#' class='samba-playlist-trigger list-group-item active' data-mediaid='" + obj.id + "'>Link</a>";
  }).join('');
  document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = ["<div>", ancoras, "</div>"].join('');
}

chamarAjax('http://sergiofrilans.se/so_pt_stuff/184974.php', myFunction);
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="id01"></div>
```

Dessa maneira tens o ajax dentro de uma função e a tua função para processar o ajax a ser passada como callback, ficando tudo mais organizado.

Comment: Bem que achei que estava meio estranho o meu código, sou novo no assunto json. Sergio, poderias me esclarecer o porque do ajax? Obrigado.

Comment: @VandréPaulo no teu código tens `xmlhttp`, é o mesmo que eu tenho, só que dei-lhe o nome `request`. O que te falta é `var request = new XMLHttpRequest();`, que se quiseres usar o teu nome de variável seria `var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();`. Isso é o que se chama de ajax, ou seja `XMLHttpRequest` é o mesmo que _pedido ajax_.

Comment: Valeu pela explicação, @Sergio. Vou fazer os ajustes e coloco o resultado aqui. Forte abraço!

Comment: @VandréPaulo de nada. Se ainda houver duvidas diz. Se a resposta solucionar o teu problema (ou resolver a maior parte) não precisas de colocar o resultado aqui. Podes clicar para aceitar a resposta. Faz como achares melhor :)

Comment: ele ainda não está a exibir no navegador. No console ele mostra o Array com os objetos perfeitamente. Só não consigo exibir no meu site, dentro da minha div, é como se ele carregasse a parte do código **<a href='#' class='samba-playlist-trigger list-group-item active' data-mediaid=" + obj.id + "></a>** vazio.

Comment: @VandréPaulo reparei num erro: falta aspas simples aqui: `data-mediaid=" + obj.id + ">`. Deve ser `data-mediaid='" + obj.id + "'>`. Se ainda não der, o que dá `console.log(typeof arr, arr);` na linha depois de `var arr = JSON.parse(response);`?

Comment: ele mostra `object [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]` e todos o conteúdo do Array

Comment: @VandréPaulo ok, então isso não é uma `array`... o que dá `console.log(Object.keys(arr));`? Ou melhor: `console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));`?

Comment: agora ele mostra o conteúdo direto, o que realmente eu quero exibir: `[{"id":"626aa442fb8ffe87ff98c659088843af","title":"O PROSCRITO","status":"ACTIVE","qualifier":"VIDEO","description":"<div>EUA</div><div>1943</div>...`

Comment: @VandréPaulo isso é o resultado de `console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))`?

Comment: @VandréPaulo editei a resposta, agora com um exemplo a funcionar...

Comment: isso mesmo. Eu quero exibir o titulo, a descrição e outras informações que ele tá puxando mostrando no console. Implementei o teu código, mas mesmo assim ele continua sem exibir as informações. Só no console

Comment: @VandréPaulo faz um jsFiddle que reproduza o teu problema para eu ver. Usa o url que coloquei na resposta se quiseres.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lgkccuxf/

Comment: @VandréPaulo funciona como está: http://jsfiddle.net/Lgkccuxf/ (repara que sem HTTPS porque o meu site só responde a HTTP).